# Unable to get response in my retrofit call back in android studio

Tags: android, json, rest, android-studio, retrofit

I am working on android studio. I am calling a `rest API` post method using retrofit.

**Rest API Request**

[image]

**Response**

```
{
"data": [
{
    "global_device_id": "982010",
    "msn": "002998002010",
    "relay_operate": "1"
}
],
"message": "Auxiliary Relay Status",
"transactionid": "Abdfqwe332432423ti", 
"status": "1"
}
```

**Retrofit Interface**

```
@Headers("Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded")
@FormUrlEncoded
@POST("UIP/on_demand_parameter_read")
Call<UIPResponse> getRelayResponse(
        @Header("transactionid") String tid,
        @Header("privatekey") String pk,
        @Field("global_device_id") String deviceId,
        @Field("type") String type
);
```

**Retrofit Client**

```
public static Retrofit getOnDemandRequest() {
    if (retrofitSignalStrength == null) {
        HttpLoggingInterceptor logging = new HttpLoggingInterceptor();
        logging.setLevel(HttpLoggingInterceptor.Level.BODY);
        OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient.Builder()
                .addInterceptor(logging)
                .connectTimeout(1000, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
                .readTimeout(1000,TimeUnit.SECONDS)
                .build();
        retrofitSignalStrength = new
                Retrofit.Builder().baseUrl(BASE_URL_STAT)
                .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
                .client(client)
                .build();
    }
    return retrofitSignalStrength;
}
```

**Response Model**

using [jsonpojo](http://www.jsonschema2pojo.org/) I have created a model

```
public class UIPResponse
{
@SerializedName("data")
@Expose
private List<Datum> data = null;
@SerializedName("message")
@Expose
private String message;
@SerializedName("transactionid")
@Expose
private String transactionid;
@SerializedName("status")
@Expose
private String status;

public List<Datum> getData() {
    return data;
}

public void setData(List<Datum> data) {
    this.data = data;
}

public String getMessage() {
    return message;
}

public void setMessage(String message) {
    this.message = message;
}

public String getTransactionid() {
    return transactionid;
}

public void setTransactionid(String transactionid) {
    this.transactionid = transactionid;
}

public String getStatus() {
    return status;
}

public void setStatus(String status) {
    this.status = status;
}

}
class Datum {

@SerializedName("global_device_id")
@Expose
private String globalDeviceId;
@SerializedName("msn")
@Expose
private String msn;
@SerializedName("relay_operate")
@Expose
private String relayOperate;

public String getGlobalDeviceId() {
    return globalDeviceId;
}

public void setGlobalDeviceId(String globalDeviceId) {
    this.globalDeviceId = globalDeviceId;
}

public String getMsn() {
    return msn;
}

public void setMsn(String msn) {
    this.msn = msn;
}

public String getRelayOperate() {
    return relayOperate;
}

public void setRelayOperate(String relayOperate) {
    this.relayOperate = relayOperate;
}

}
```

Finally in my `onClick` method

```
btnSubmit.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() 
    {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v)
        {

            final ProgressDialog progressDialog = new ProgressDialog(getActivity());
            progressDialog.setMessage("Sending Command.....");
            progressDialog.setProgressStyle(ProgressDialog.STYLE_SPINNER);
            progressDialog.setIndeterminate(true);
            progressDialog.setCancelable(false);
            progressDialog.show();

            Retrofit retrofit = RetrofitClient.getOnDemandRequest();
            RetrofitInterface retrofitInterface = retrofit.create(RetrofitInterface.class);
            Call<UIPResponse> call = retrofitInterface.getRelayResponse(transactionid, privatekey, global_device_id,type);

            call.enqueue(new retrofit2.Callback<UIPResponse>() {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(Call<UIPResponse> call, Response<UIPResponse> response) {
                    Log.d("Retrofit", "response received: " + response.toString());
                    boolean isSuccess = false;

                    if(response.isSuccessful())
                    {
                        isSuccess = true;
                    }
                    progressDialog.dismiss();
                    if (!isSuccess)
                    {

                    }
                    else
                    {

                    }

                }

                @Override
                public void onFailure(Call<UIPResponse> call, Throwable t) {
                    Log.d("Retrofit", "error occured: " + t.toString());
                }
            });


            progressDialog.dismiss();
        }

    });
```

When I run my `app` and clicks on `send` button. I am not getting any thing in `onResponse` or `onFailure`. But the `API` is executed and I am getting response in my `logcat`

**Logcat**

```
2020-08-12 15:40:46.947 3449-3589/com.thumbsol.accuratemobileassetsmanagament D/OkHttp: --> POST port:IP/program/…
2020-08-12 15:40:46.947 3449-3589/com.thumbsol.accuratemobileassetsmanagament D/OkHttp: Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded
2020-08-12 15:40:46.948 3449-3589/com.thumbsol.accuratemobileassetsmanagament D/OkHttp: Content-Length: 33
2020-08-12 15:40:46.949 3449-3589/com.thumbsol.accuratemobileassetsmanagament D/OkHttp: transactionid: Arewwsadas32fff4bt
2020-08-12 15:40:46.949 3449-3589/com.thumbsol.accuratemobileassetsmanagament D/OkHttp: privatekey: 8ercq52hiob2312ewqd3
2020-08-12 15:40:46.949 3449-3589/com.thumbsol.accuratemobileassetsmanagament D/OkHttp: global_device_id=982010&type=AUXR
2020-08-12 15:40:46.949 3449-3589/com.thumbsol.accuratemobileassetsmanagament D/OkHttp: --> END POST (33-byte body)
2020-08-12 15:40:50.771 3449-3589/com.thumbsol.accuratemobileassetsmanagament D/OkHttp: <-- 200 port:IP/program/… (3821ms)
2020-08-12 15:40:50.772 3449-3589/com.thumbsol.accuratemobileassetsmanagament D/OkHttp: Content-Type: text/json;charset=UTF-8
2020-08-12 15:40:50.772 3449-3589/com.thumbsol.accuratemobileassetsmanagament D/OkHttp: Content-Length: 180
2020-08-12 15:40:50.772 3449-3589/com.thumbsol.accuratemobileassetsmanagament D/OkHttp: Date: Wed, 12 Aug 2020 10:40:51 GMT
2020-08-12 15:40:50.773 3449-3589/com.thumbsol.accuratemobileassetsmanagament D/OkHttp: {"data":[{"global_device_id":"982010","msn":"002998002010","relay_operate":"0"}],"message":"Auxiliary Relay Status","transactionid":"Abdfqwe332432423ti","status":"1"}
2020-08-12 15:40:50.773 3449-3589/com.thumbsol.accuratemobileassetsmanagament D/OkHttp: <-- END HTTP (180-byte body)
```

I am stuck and don't know what to further.

Any help would be highly appreciated.

Comment: Try to show `Toast` message in `onResponse` or `onFailure`.

Comment: Yes the toast is appearing on the screen

Comment: Then your onResponse is working. To get `UIPResponse` call response.body()

Comment: @Bek I am unable to get the data from my `"data": [
{
    "global_device_id": "982010",
    "msn": "002998002010",
    "relay_operate": "1"
}
],` list. I am using `response.body().getData()` but I don't know that what should I pass to get the `relay_operate` and etc

Comment: `response.body().getData().get(0).getRelayOperate()`

Comment: `getRelayOperate() in Datum is defined in an inaccessible class or interface`

Comment: Make Datum `public`

Comment: It's not allowing me make it public :(

Comment: `error: class Datum is public, should be declared in a file named Datum.java
public class Datum {
       ^`

Comment: Do what it says